# Show that $ \ \lambda \leq \|A^TA\|$.

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-norms

Let $ \lambda $ be the eigenvalue of $A^TA$, $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$.

Let $\|\cdot\|$ be a norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$ with associated subordinate matrix $\|\cdot\|$ on $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$.

Show that $ \ \lambda \leq \|A^TA\|$.

If $x \neq 0$, then $(A^TA) x=\lambda x \Rightarrow ||A^TA||=\lambda$.

But I have to show $||A^TA|| \geq \lambda$.

Comment: If $A^TA v = \lambda v$ with $\|v\|=1$ then $\|A^TA\| \ge \| A^TAv\|= |\lambda|$.

Comment: What are your thoughts? What have you tried? Questions posed like this are usually poorly received on this site.

Comment: @copper.hat, I mean I have to show that $ ||A^TA|| \geq \lambda$.

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR: I do not understand your last comment.

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR: My first comment answers the question...

Comment: Can you please include the precise definition of $||.||$ norm in your question?

Comment: @MostafaAyaz: It works or an arbitrary norm and the corresponding induced norm on matrices. The first comment above is the proof.